# Visualizing binary timeseries data in python

Tags: python, time-series, visualization, data-visualization

I've got a collection of a few different binary timeseries that I'd like to visualize on top of one another. The series are composed of cycle data, so each data point looks like `(start_ts, end_ts, state)`, where `start_ts` and `end_ts` are both floats and `state` is a boolean

Each time series is composed of a list of tuples like the one above, yielding something like

```
[(t0, t1, s1),
 (t1, t2, s2),
 ...
 (tn-1, tn, sn)]
```

For example, you might have something like

```
[(0, 5, TRUE),
 (5, 23, FALSE),
 (23, 38, TRUE)]
```

signifying that, for that particular time series, the value was TRUE from 0 seconds to 5 seconds, FALSE from 5 second to 23 seconds, and then TRUE again from 23 seconds to 38 seconds

In the end, I'd like output that looks like

```
series_1  XXXXXOOOOOXXXXXOOXOOOXO
series_2  XXXXXXXXOOOOOOXXXXXXOOO
series_3  XXXXOOOOXXXXXXXXXXOOOXX
```

but as a colored chart, not as a series of X's and O's

Do you have any recommendations on the best way to visualize this? Thank you!

**UPDATE**
I've started working on anishtain4's solution with the code below. I found I needed to concatenate and flatten the list

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def convert_to_np_list(cycles):
  series_i_shape=[np.ones(int(b[1]-b[0]))*b[2] for b in cycles]
  flattened_shape = np.concatenate(series_i_shape).ravel()
  return flattened_shape

truth_list = convert_to_np_list(truth_cycles)
pred_list = convert_to_np_list(pred_cycles)

print truth_list.shape
print pred_list.shape

timeshape=np.c_[truth_list, pred_list]
plt.pcolor(timeshape.T)
```

Comment: Can you tell us how does your input look like? is it a list? string? array?

Comment: Great question -- sorry about that. I'll add it in now!

Comment: And the values inside the tuples are string? int? boolean?

Comment: Is each tuple a structure like:
( start_time_of_1sequence, end_time_of_1sequence, sequence_id ) ?
example: [(0,2,0),(4,5,1)]=11010

Comment: Just updated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm not sure how many time series you have and how they are stored, first I'll explain how to do it for each time series. This converts every series to a set of zeros and ones.

`series_i_shape=[np.ones(b[1]-b[0])*b[2] for b in series_i]`

Then stack them up in columns:

`timeshape=np.c_[series_1_shape,series_2_shape,...]`

Then you can plot it using `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`:

`plt.pcolor(timeshape.T)`

Comment: This looks really promising! Thank you for your help, and sorry for the delay. I'm having some trouble getting it to work. I've updated the code above